# Changing $scope from inside $rootScope is not getting reflected

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to show one button as in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wPxxfHVYMnzDp4Ib77DJ?p=preview)

```
<div ng-show="showbtn"><button class="fix btn btn-success" ng-click="top()">To the top</button></div>
```

On scroll event, I have made `$rootScope.$emit` call and it is getting triggered too, but not sure why the `$scope` value is not getting changed inside the `mainCtrl` controller $scope. Is `$scope` inside `$rootScope` is different ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event handler (the function passed to `$rootScope.$on`) runs outside of Angular's normal digest cycle so you need to tell the parent scope that something has changed. You can use [`$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) to do so:

```
$rootScope.$on('scrolled',function(event,data){
  $scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.showbtn = data.message;
  });
});
```

Here's an [updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WyA7C6gyHCbkqnHwfPMj?p=preview).